# Using range function in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I am new to learning Python and have a question about using the range function to iterate a string.

Let's say I need to capitalize everything in the following string:

`string = 'a b c d e f g'`

Can I just write the following code?

```
for i in string:
    i = i.upper()
return string
```

Or should I use the range function to iterate every element in the string?

Finally, a more general question is whenever I need to iterate all elements in a string/list, when should I use the range function and when can I just use the "for" loop?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. You need to concatenate `i.upper()` to a new string.

Comment: Every string in Python ist iterable, so don't use another generator like range. But if your string is `"a b c d e f g"`, every second element is a space `" "`. Here you'd use `for i in "a b c d e f g".split(" ")` ;) (and concatenate in a new variable as Barmar said)

Comment: Did you mean: `string = string.upper()`?

Comment: Your example doesn't work, because `i = i.upper()` does not reassign the uppercase letter back to the original string.  The uppercase letter is stored in a local variable `i` which is never used. The example can be rewritten as just `return string.upper()`.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are a bad example, because strings in Python cannot be changed.  You have to build a new one:

```
new = ''
for i in string:
    new += i.upper()
```

For the sake of example, we're all going to ignore the fact that `new = string.upper()` would do this in one statement.

In general, when you iterate through an object, you are handed references to the members.  You can't change the container object, but if the inner object is mutable, you can change it.  Consider this silly example:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
for element in a:
    element[0] *= 2
```

This will result in `a` being `[[2],[4],[6],[8]]`, because we are allowed to modify those inner lists.  We can't change the outer list.

AS A GENERAL RULE, if you find yourself writing `for i in range(len(xxx)):`, then there is a better way to do it. It isn't ALWAYS true, but it's a key Python learning point.

Comment: If you just work with the value and don't need the index, you'd "in general" use `for i in xxx` to not add another indirection, especially for _very_ large arrays / iterables. Adding range and len just adds two function calls and iterates the `xxx` nonetheless. In most cases there's a better option than iterating via index (generators, comprehension, vectorized functions, ...)

Comment: Exactly right.  Either `for i in xxx: ` or `for idx,i in enumerate(xxx):` is virtually always a better solution.